# Problemas con zip y append en una lista en python

Tags: python, lista

Estoy creando un programa en donde el usuario ingrese tres datos: nombre, edad y ciudad
Mi idea es que se generen listas, para que, posteriormente, pueda unir todos los datos ingresados por medio de `zip`. De esta manera, crear una lista con tuplas que sean conformadas por `[(name, age, city), (name, age, city), ...]` hasta que el usuario lo desee. Sin embargo, tengo problemas al agregar los datos ingresados en una variable y por lo tanto, aplicar correctamente `zip`.
He escrito lo siguiente:

```
nombres = []
edad = []
ciudad = []
combinacion = list(zip(nombres, edad, ciudad))

print("Para terminar, ingresa 't'")

while True:
    name = input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")
    age = int(input("Ingresa tu edad: "))
    city = input("Ingresa tu ciudad: ")
    
    pregunta = input("¿Desea terminar? s/n")
    if pregunta == "s":
        break
    elif pregunta == "n":
        continue
    
    nombres.append(name)
    edad.append(age)
    ciudad.append(city)
    
    combinacion.append(name, age, city)

print(combinacion)
```

¿Qué podría modificar para crear: `[(name, age, city), (name, age, city)...]`?

Comment: Quita ese `combinacion.append()` y fuera del ciclo `while` coloca `combinacion = list(zip((nombres, edad, ciudad))`

Answer (score 0):

La solución ya la dije en los comentarios.
Primero debes eliminar ese `combinacion.append(name, age, city)`. Esto dará error ya que `append` acepta un solo parámetro y tu le pasas 3.

Luego que quitar esa línea deberás hacer el `zip` que es correcto tal y como lo haces en la inicialización de la variable al inicio del código, solo que ahora debe de ir al final.

```py
combinacion = list(zip(nombres, edad, ciudad))
```

Con esto ya estaría tu problema casi arreglado. Digo casi ya que en realidad tienes otro problema en las condiciones

```py
    if pregunta == "s":
        break
    elif pregunta == "n":
        continue
   ...
```

En caso el usuario ingrese `n` el ciclo volverá al inicio saltándose todo lo demás, lo que incluye la parte del código donde agregas el dato ingresado a la lista correspondiente, eso provoca que tus listas `nombres`, `edad` y `ciudad` siempre estén vacías. Esto se soluciona poniendo solo la condición del `break`

```
    if pregunta == "s": #puedes usar pregunta.lower() para evitar sensitive case
        break

    nombres.append(name)
    edad.append(age)
    ciudad.append(city)
```

Con esto ya estaría tu código funcionando, solo voy a aclarar unas pequeñas cosas.

Al principio dije que `.append` acepta 1 solo parámetro, que es el elemento a insertar, si quieres insertar varios elementos puedes usar `.extend` o usar el operador de concatenación `+=` donde el valor que le asignes deberá ser una lista.

Sin embargo, puedes lograr el resultado que deseas sin usar `zip`. Pues solo basta con insertar una tupla a la lista `cobinación`. El código quedaría así:

```py
while True:
    name = input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")
    age = int(input("Ingresa tu edad: "))
    city = input("Ingresa tu ciudad: ")
    
    pregunta = input("¿Desea terminar? s/n")
    if pregunta == "s":
        break
    
    combiacion.append( (name, age, city) ) #agregamos una tupla

print(combinacion)
```

Esto nos dará el mismo resultado que el utilizar `zip` además que dejamos de lado el usar 3 listas para almacenar valores (a menos que así lo requieras).